# Python 3 object creation consumes large amounts of memory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a list of instances of user-defined classes. These instances contain many matrices which are created inside the constructor of the class. The total size of such an instance, measured with pympler, is 1.2 MB.

When creating these objects one after another, something weird happens. When the first object is created, the system-wide memory usage only increases insignificantly, however, when the second object is created, it uses more than 1 GB of system-wide memory. This memory usage is not reflected inside python, i.e. pympler still says that memory usage has increased by 1.2 MB. This goes on for each newly created object, with every second using huge amounts of memory.

Is there a way to see what causes this memory usage?

For clarity, I have included the respective (pseudo) code below:

```
class ClassA:
    class SubClass:
        def __init__(self, ...):
            self.matrix_a = np.zeros(256)
            self.matrix_b = np.zeros(256)
            self.matrix_c = np.zeros(256)

    def __init__(self, ...):
        self.subitems = []
        for i in range(0, 100000):
            self.subitems.append(ClassA.SubClass(self, ...)
```

Comment: Why the `multithreading` tag?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, this problem occurred in a multithreading environment, so when originally formulating the question, I thought it could have something to do with that. Meanwhile, however, I have eliminated this as a reason, as it also occurs in a single-threaded setting.